# Current Filename in AsciiDoc

Tags: asciidoctor

Is there some variable like the 'imagepath' in AsciiDoc/Asciidoctor which gives me the current source file?

I would like to use this in order to render a link to the sources...

couldn't find this on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Asciidoctor (http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#env-attributes) try

docdir, docname, docfile

These are for the outer document only - there is no way to get the name of #included files.

Asciidoc additionally has infile and indir for the current #include.